# Gradle - Adding new configuration to classpath throws error

Tags: gradle, plugins, configuration, classpath

I have created a custom Gradle plugin which creates a new configuration for some dependencies that I want to treat separately. Since these used to be in the `compile` configuration I have added the new configuration to the classpath (from the Java plugin) like so:

```
project.sourceSets.all { sourceSet -> 
    sourceSet.compileClasspath += myConfiguration
}
```

My configuration *extends* the `compile` configuration. My reasoning for this was that if there were any other 3rd party plugins that did "something" to the `compile` configuration then it would also affect my new configuration, since it is also an instance of `compile`.

It seems that later on another plugin, the [Spring PropDeps Plugin](https://github.com/spring-gradle-plugins/propdeps-plugin), also modifies the classpath and the build fails with:

> Failed to apply plugin [class 'org.springframework.build.gradle.propdep.PropDepsPlugin']
>   Cannot change dependencies of configuration ':my-project:compile' after it has been resolved.

Looking at the source code for that plugin they are doing the same steps that I am in my custom plugin to create a configuration, namely create the configuration and add it to the classpath as soon as the plugin is applied, see [here](https://github.com/spring-gradle-plugins/propdeps-plugin/blob/master/src/main/groovy/io/spring/gradle/propdeps/PropDepsPlugin.groovy).

It would seem crazy if only *one* plugin could add a new configuration to the classpath. What am I doing wrong here?

Note that my custom plugin is applied in the `allprojects` block whereas the Spring plugin is applied in the `subprojects` block - not sure if this matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm ... as I was writing the question something struck me about both extending the `compile` configuration *and* adding to the compile classpath. This seemed like I was adding a circular dependency. Low and behold, when I did not extend the configuration the build worked!